# Sorting Nestable Structure Index in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sorting, nested, sql-order-by

There is a table `Article`. I want to sort data like this.

Check after records `4.2.1`.

Thank you for four suggestion and help.

I want to sort this data:

```
ArticleCode        
------------
1
1.1
1.2
1.3
2
3
3.1
3.2
3.3
3.4
3.5
4
4.1
4.1.1
4.1.2
4.1.3
4.2
4.2.1
4.2.2
4.2.3
4.2.4
4.2.5
4.2.6
4.2.7
4.2.8
4.2.9
4.2.10
4.2.11
4.2.12
```

My select query:

```
select ArticleCode 
from Article 
order by ArticleCode
```

Query result:

```
1
1.1
1.2
1.3
2
3
3.1
3.2
3.3
3.4
3.5
4
4.1
4.1.1
4.1.2
4.1.3
4.2
4.2.1
4.2.10
4.2.11
4.2.12
4.2.2
4.2.3
4.2.4
4.2.5
4.2.6
4.2.7
4.2.8
4.2.9
```

Comment: This is because you are sorting concatenated strings and you want instead to sort each element. The best solution would be properly normalize this data and get this data into three columns. This data structure here violates 1NF by shoving multiple data points into a single column. Are you able to change the data structure or are you stuck and have to sort this?

Comment: To add to what @SeanLange stated, this isn't unique to SQL Server either. If you drop this in Excel as TEXT you'll get the same, string sort order. It's no different than the letter a coming before the letter A.

Comment: Structre cannot be applied into three columns because it's dynamic. Depth can be infinite.

Comment: Is there any way sort this type of data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way you can do this. It will support a reasonable depth (892 bytes), but not infinite. Also this is going to be pretty slow on a large dataset but not sure you can avoid performance problems here with the data structure you have.

```
declare @article table(ArticleCode varchar(10))

insert @article values
('1')
, ('1.1')
, ('1.2')
, ('1.3')
, ('2')
, ('3')
, ('3.1')
, ('3.2')
, ('3.3')
, ('3.4')
, ('3.5')
, ('4')
, ('4.1')
, ('4.1.1')
, ('4.1.2')
, ('4.1.3')
, ('4.2')
, ('4.2.1')
, ('4.2.10')
, ('4.2.11')
, ('4.2.12')
, ('4.2.2')
, ('4.2.3')
, ('4.2.4')
, ('4.2.5')
, ('4.2.6')
, ('4.2.7')
, ('4.2.8')
, ('4.2.9')

select *
from @article
order by convert(hierarchyid, '/' + replace(ArticleCode, '.', '/') + '/') --have to append the / before and after so the values are a valid hierarchyid
```

Comment: Thank you for your intensive support. I think I cannot avoid the performance problems. Because there are huge data. But this is a correct answer.